# The name 'Task' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. | Flutter & Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I just got an error. It says :

```
> The name 'Task' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
> 
> Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named
> 'Task'.
```

Here's the snippet code :

```
Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  initialData: [],
                  future: _dbHelper.getTasks(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>> snapshot) {
                    return ScrollConfiguration(
                      behavior: NoGlowBehaviour(),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Taskpage(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: TaskCardWidget(
                              title: snapshot.data![index].title,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Here's the snippet code Picture :
[image: Snippet Error Code Frans]

Here's my full code: https://github.com/kisekifrans/todo_furans

If I imported the task library, more errors showed up.

Please help me out with this, and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task seems like a class defined in `https://github.com/kisekifrans/todo_furans/blob/main/lib/models/task.dart`. Of course you should import here to use it.

Importing `Task` causes other error, which is `The argument type 'ScrollConfiguration Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>)'`, just change

```dart
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>> snapshot) {
```

to

```dart
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
```

Comment: You're just missing the T parameter of the constructor, so the compiler is inferring that T is `List<dynamic>`, which is wrong.  Change `FutureBuilder(` to `FutureBuilder<List<Task>>(` and you should get the proper type matching.

Comment: Also, your future should be in a state variable, not created as part of the "future:" parameter.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg for why.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Very good point. We should take advantage of the typed system and avoid using dynamic. Thanks Randal.

Comment: And @Frans, you should consider reformatting `_dbHelper.getTasks(),` as a variable inside the state class, and take the variable to be used as the value of the `future:` field as Randal's video suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do the trick. Notice the commented lines where the changes are.

First, you need to import `Task` with:

```dart
import 'package:todo_furans/models/task.dart';
```

Second, you need to remove the `AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>>` type redefinition on the `snapshot` parameter. This is because `snapshot` has a type already that comes from the default `FutureBuilder<Object?>` and Dart errors out telling the function signature types are not compatible with `AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>`. So, the easiest way is to declare `FutureBuilder` itself with the type you want `snapshot` to be. Like `FutureBuilder<List<Task>>`.

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Task>>( // <- Here
  initialData: [],
  future: _dbHelper.getTasks(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) { // <- Here
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: NoGlowBehaviour(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Taskpage(
                    task: snapshot.data![index],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: TaskCardWidget(
              title: snapshot.data![index].title,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Finally, I'd recommend checking if `snapshot.data` is `null` first instead of forcing it to non-null with `!` operator. While it's null just show a [`CircularProgressIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) to indicate it's still loading.

Comment: I've simplified it a bit more. The easiest way is to declare `FutureBuilder` itself like `FutureBuilder<List<Task>>`. This way you're going to get `snapshot` with the right data type already.